# gnuplot from tailing a file

Tags: linux, shell-script

Is it possible to use gnuplot to create a chart that dynamically grows as output is received by a log file?

For example, I can run something like:

```
tail -f mylog.txt | grep "Row I care about" | cut -b 35-45
```

Is there a way to use gnuplot to create a chart that dynamically updates with each new line written to the log?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44471008/2072269?

Comment: Thanks, not really dynamic.  I remember years ago seeing a guy who had it working and now I can't do it.